# A true evaluated \ifnum in a tikzpicture \draw command is failing to work as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

My minimal example looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle
    %\ifnum 0=1 node{My Label} \fi  % Works correctly when the value = 0
    \ifnum 1=1 node{My Label} \fi   % Fails to draw
    %node{My label}                 % What I expect when the value passed in = 1
    (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This previous thread suggests it should work: [Conditional within TikZ path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284719/conditional-within-tikz-path)

I notice this similar question, which differs in that the question there wants to make entire parts conditional, whereas I'm looking to make only a part of a `\draw` line conditional: [Numerical conditional within tikz keys?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156535/numerical-conditional-within-tikz-keys)

The reported error looks like this:

```
! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                              
l.10 \ifnum 1=1 n
                 ode{My Label} \fi  % Fails to draw
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.


! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

I'm using MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.7338 (1.40.21) (MiKTeX 2.9.7400 64-bit) on Windows 10, inside TeXStudio 2.12.22, if that is relevant.

The command to start the build is `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "tikz_error".tex`

Comment: it doesn't work, your \ifnum interrupts the parsing process. You can use the \edef method in the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you *can* use `\ifnum` etc. in paths. There are, however, cases in which Ti*k*Z expects some explicit character, or so. In this case you can just add the `\ifnum` stuff to the node contents to make Ti*k*Z happy.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle
    %node{\ifnum0=1\relax My Label\fi}  % Works correctly when the value = 0
    node{\ifnum1=1\relax My Label\fi}   % Works correctly
    (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Out of interest, what does \relax do?

Comment: @Arkady "Nothing". To be more precise, in this context it terminates the `\ifnum` comparison. While here it is not necessary (except perhaps to suppress spurious spaces) you can use it in constructions like `\ifnum1=1\relax0 ...` to make sure the the `0` does not get appended to `1` and the comparison is `1=10`, which is false.)

Answer (score 3):

You can expand the `\ifnum` prior to executing the `\draw`, to avoid the parsing issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\tmp{\draw (0,0) rectangle}
  \expandafter\tmp
    \ifnum 1=1 node{My Label} \fi   % Draws label
    (4,4);
  \expandafter\tmp
    \ifnum 1=2 node{My Alt Label} \fi   % Omits label
    (-4,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]